# Change URL and block access to old URL

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting

I have a web application developed in CakePHP and I use Routing.prefixes to access administration pages ... so let's say the website URL is http://www.mysite.com, I have all administration pages go under http://www.mysite.com/admin.

For example, for users management I would have http://www.mysite.com/admin/users/create, http://www.mysite.com/admin/users/edit etc.

Now for security reason I want to change the URL for the admin pages to more obscure URL like http://www.mysite.com/myobscureadmin which I want to redirect that to the current http://www.mysite.com/admin while at the same time I want to block access to http://www.mysite.com/admin

I am wondering if I can achieve this without much changes on my CakePHP codes. It doesn't matter if I do it through .htaccess or CakePHP routing rules ... as long as the code changes are minimal.

Any input will be much appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, you should always use example.com

Comment: will remember that in my future posts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you should be working to beef up your site security, as that will stand you in better stead than 'security in obscurity'. As for your question, I would tackle this in the routes file, by just adding a new route.

Router::connect('/myobscureadmin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));

http://api.cakephp.org/class/router#method-Routerconnect

Comment: thanks for your response DavidYell ... fyi this doesn't replace the security itself ... it is just on the top of it. Could you give me an example on ho to put it in the routes file? thanks.

Comment: Updated, sorry I got dragged into a meeting :)

Comment: Hi DavidYell, thanks for your update ... I however needed to modify the code a bit because the new admin URL should apply to multiple controllers. This is what I have:

Router::connect('/myobscureadmin/:controller/:action/*', array('prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));